# What is the difference between Tomcat and Tomcat Native?

Tags: java, react-native, tomcat

The tomcat is a well-known Apache licensed web server. There are many stable versions. The one I have been using is Tomcat 8.
Recently, a new NATIVE version is released as is quoted from the Apache website.

> The Apache Tomcat is proud to announce the release of 1.2.24 of Tomcat Native.

Could someone explain what the difference is between Tomcat Native and Tomcat? Also, when we refer to a software framework as a NATIVE framework e.g. React Native, what do we really mean?

Comment: This is a better question for ServerFault and here is a discussion on this topic there: https://serverfault.com/questions/367842/is-tomcat-native-worth-the-trouble

Comment: Tomcat Native is a small *piece* of Tomcat.

Answer (score 1):

Tomcat Native optimizes the performance of Tomcat in high concurrency environments.
If Linux has installed APR and native, Tomcat directly supports APR.
Simply put, native is a Linux plug-in used to improve Tomcat concurrency.

[Tomcat Native docs](https://tomcat.apache.org/native-doc/)

[Tomcat 9 Docs](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/index.html)